# AWS CLI query return on one line

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I have the following CLI command in a shell file. I can't figure out how to get the output to come out all on 1 line:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[], PrivateIpAddress]' --output text
```

The output comes out like this

```
instance1
10.10.1.10
instance2
10.10.1.11
```

instead of:

```
instance1 10.10.1.10
instance2 10.10.1.11
```

I know the solution has something to do with the placement of the "[]"s.  I tried moving and removing them in various ways.

How can I get my output to line up?

Comment: Try `--output table`

Comment: What is `instance1` in the actual output? The name tag, the instance ID, ...?

Comment: @jarmod "instance1" is the value of the "Name" tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline is a result of the `Tags` being an array that can have multiple values.

You can avoid the newline by specifying that you only want the *first* entry in the array:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0], PrivateIpAddress]' --output text
```

The result is:

```
one 172.30.0.19
two 172.30.1.210
```